# What was the original reason for MATLAB's one function = one file and why is it still so?

Tags: matlab

What was the original reason for MATLAB's one *(primary)* function = one file, and why is it still so, after so many years of development?

What are the advantages of this approach, compared to its disadvantages (people put too many things in functions and scripts, when they should obviously be separated ... resulting in loss of code clarity)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab's schema of loading one class/function per file seems to match Java's choice in this matter. I am betting that there were other technical reasons for speeding up the parser in when it was introduced the 1980's. This schema was chosen by Java to discourage extremely large files with everything stuffed inside, which has been the primary argument for any language I've seen using one-file class symantics.

However, forcing one class per file semantics doesn't stop mega files -- [KPIB](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12051-kpib-kenny-purpose-interface-bus) is a perfect example of a complicated, horrifically long function/class file (though a quite useful maga file). So the one class file system is a way of trying to make the user aware about code abstraction more than a functionally useful mechanism.

A positive result of the one function/class file system of Matlab is that it's very easy to know what functions are available at a quick glance of a project directory. Additionally many of the names had to be made descriptive enough to differentiate them from other files, so naming as a minor form of documentation is present as a side effect.

In the end I don't think there are strong arguments for or against one file classes as it's usually just a minor semantically change to go from onw to the other (unless your code is in a horribly unorganized state... in which case you should be shamed into fixing it).

**EDIT!**

I fixed the bad reference to Matlab adopting Java's one class file system -- after more research it appears that both developers adopted this style independently (or rather didn't specify that the other language influenced their decision). This is especially true since Matlab didn't bundle Java until 2000.

Comment: I am pretty sure Matlab has had this structure since well before Java existed.

Comment: Opps, you're 100% correct. I should have looked into that more before writing what I had heard from word of mouth.

Comment: Starting from the end and going towards the beginning of your answer: It has
been my experience that it results in mess-ier functions. What could be
separated and "packaged" as a simple function that does only one thing, is often
not, but instead mixed up with other code, resulting in one larger function that
does several things. It discourages dividing code into proper separated
entities, because people get tired with managing large number of files in their
projects.

As far as the question what is "better", one function per file, or

Comment: one "giant"
file, I would still prefer one giant file approach - although messy, at least it
is usually easier to pack and transport it.

Still would like to see this restriction removed, though.

p.s. Yup, MATLAB had this restriction since its earliest versions, somewhere down in the early 90s (don't recall what version it was when I started using it).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there any advantage. But you can put as many functions as you need in a single file.
For example:

```
classdef UTILS
    methods (Static)
        function help
            % prints help for all functions
            disp(char(methods(mfilename, '-full')));
        end
        function func_01()
        end
        function func_02()
        end
        % ...more functions
    end
end
```

I find it very neat.

```
>> UTILS.help
obj UTILS     
Static func_01
Static func_02
Static help 

>> UTILS.func_01()
```

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that (but my programs are all rather simply structured ... scripts and main level functions only).