# Are forward declarations supported in MATLAB?

Tags: function, matlab, forward-declaration

Is it possible to use a function in a m-file, which is implemented in a later part of the same file: in similar style to other programming languages such as C?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Of course.

In such an m-file, the local functions would be declared after the main function. For example:

```
function y = main_func(x)
% # This is the main function
y = helper_func1(x) .* helper_func2(x);  % # Just an example

function h1 = helper_func1(x)
% # This is a helper function #1
h1 = x + 2;                              % # Just an example

function h2 = helper_func2(x)
% # This is a helper function #2
h2 = x * 2;                              % # Just an example
```

In this example `main_func` can invoke `helper_func1` and `helper_func2` without any problems. You can test-run it and see for yourself:

```
   >> main_func(8)

   ans =        
       160
```

There is no need for any forward declaration.

By the way, a lot of m-files that come with MATLAB are implemented this way. For instance, [`corrcoef`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/corrcoef.html). With `type corrcoef`, you can see that.

Note: local function definitions are not permitted at the prompt or in scripts, so you have to have declare a "main" function in your m-file. As an exercise, copy-paste my example into a new m-file, remove the declaration of `main_func` (only the first line) and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same m-file for implementation of many functions using a static class:

[What was the original reason for MATLAB's one function = one file and why is it still so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414041/what-was-the-original-reason-for-matlabs-one-function-one-file-and-why-is-it/12414225#12414225)