# MATLAB function syntax within script?

Tags: function, matlab, syntax

Having some trouble declaring functions within my script:

%Read the raw audio data

```
refData = wavread('file1.wav');
userData = wavread('file2.wav'); 

% I want to continue writing my "main" function here, and call the below functions

%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Functions %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Vector x
function preEmphasis(x)
    alpha = 0.95;
    len = length(x);
    for i=1:len
        x_i = x(i);
        x_iMinus1 = x(i-1);
        x(i) = x_i - alpha*x_iMinus1;
    end
end

%Vector x
function normalization(x)
    maxVal = max(abs(x));
    x = x / maxVal;
end

%Vector x; numFrames, frameSize: integers; stepSize: percentage (float, 0.2 -> 0.5 for example)
function Ymatrix = createYmatrix(x, numFrames, frameSize, stepSize)
        Ymatrix = zeros(numFrames, frameSize);
        for i=1:numFrames
            for j=1:frameSize
                Ymatrix(i,j) = x(stepSize*i + j);
            end
        end
end
```

The words "function" and "end" are highlighted in red as "parse errors". How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't declare functions within your main script. You have to create an external m-file and implement your function inside it, like it says in the [official documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/scripts-and-functions.html?s_tid=doc_12b#f4-25176):

> Any function that is not [anonymous](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html?s_tid=doc_12b) must be defined within a file.

(just to be clear, a script does not accept input arguments or return output arguments).

However, you can have local functions declared inside a function m-file. 
Read more about function declarations in [the official documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html).

**EDIT:** You can Refer to @natan's answer if you're looking for a way to avoid function m-files altogether. He implemented your functions as [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html?s_tid=doc_12b), which *can* be declared inside the script file. Good luck!

Comment: "Local functions inside an m-file" Isn't that what I'm trying to do here? At least that's what I would want... tired of this multiple file nonsense for quick scripting lol.

Comment: I believe not. I think it's your main script, since it doesn't have a function declaration in its the beginning.

Comment: But otherwise what I'm doing with function ... end is correct and I can just move all the functions into another file?

Comment: The `end` is optional in the case of your function. Just create an m-file named "mymainfunc.m", that starts with for example: `function y = mymainfunc(x)`, implement it and copy paste the rest of your functions inside it. Then call `mymainfunc` from your main script. **Note**: your m-file must be called like the main function in that file. Also, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13331299/1336150) might also clear things up...

Comment: If you want "quick" scripting, you can always make a function `run` in a `run.m` file, and implement _everything_ inside it. You'd still have to make a main script and invoke `run`, though... OR just try to manage without functions :)

Comment: By the way, food for thought: you can make some of your functions anonymous, and they _can_ be defined in your script. For example: `normalization = @(x)(x / max(abs(x)));`

Answer (score 1):

In Addition to what Eitan mentioned, here is how to implement an anonymous functions in your case, note that code vectorization is a must. For example, in your case instead of `normalization` you can write:

```
normalization = @(x) x./max(abs(x));
```

and then use it as if it was a function, `y=normalization(x)`

For `preEmphasis`:

```
preEmphasis= @(x) [x(1) x(2:end)-0.95*x(1:end-1)];
```

Your current code has a bug for the case `i=1` so I interpret that as `for=2:len` instead;

The solution for `Ymatrix` is a bit ugly (haven't invested to much time vectorizing it nicely), but it should work:

```
Ymatrix = @(x, numFrames, frameSize, stepSize) ...
          ones(1,numFrames)'*x(1+stepSize:stepSize+frameSize)+...
          meshgrid(0:stepSize:stepSize*numFrames-1,ones(1,frameSize))';
```

Comment: LOL, I've just suggested it in one of my comments :) +1 anyway. I wonder if `createYmatrix` can be made into an anonymous function :P

Comment: yes Ymatrix can be made to an anonymous function, see my edit

Answer (score 1):

Just turn your script into a function; then you can use local and nested functions. Use return values or `assignin` if you need to get values back in to the base or caller's workspace.